# set host-name failed on Ubuntu vivid

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, linux-networking, hostname

With Ubuntu vivid, I cannot bind the `hostname` of my server with the IP address gotten by a DHCP server

I tried to add in dhclient.conf (and reboot)

```
set host-name "myserver";
```

But, still doesn't work...

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name, edit the /etc/hostname and run:

```
hostname $(cat /etc/hostname)
```